# Database Logging Table Structure

Tags: database-design, logging

I'm creating some database tables for storing log entries. Under normal circumstances I would always normalize and never stuff values together, but I'm not 100% convinced that's a good idea here.

I could normalize and have:

- LogEntry
- LogEntryCategory
- LogCategory
- LogEntryProperty

LogEntry has a many to many relationship with LogCategory and a LogEntry has a 1 to many with LogEntryProperty (which are name/value pairs).

Alternative is a denormalized version which has just LogEntry with categories stored as a comma delimited list of string categories and properties stored as a comma limited list of Name: Value formatted properties. As ugly as this sounds, from a reporting, performance, and searchability perspective, I'm not sure if this isn't better.

Which is a better idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea of possible number of log-entry properties?

Comment: Hundreds of thousands over time but probably archived

Comment: Sorry, I meant distinct names in your name-value pair.

Comment: Oh. Probably 15-20 or so categories. Each log entry will have 0 to maybe 5 properties. Most will have 0.

Answer (score 8):

Because there are only a **few distinct properties**, I would stay away from name-value pairs and give each property a separate table **with a proper name and data-type**. I have used generic `Property_`, just for the  demo.

[image]

The thing here is to make sure not to insert a value into a property table if it is missing, in other words all property values are NOT NULL.

To make life easier, define a view

```
create view dbo.vLogs AS
select
      LogCategoryName
    , LogTime
    , p1_Value
    , p2_Value
    , p3_Value
    , p4_Value
    , p5_Value  
from LogEntry              as e
left join Property_1       as p1 on p1.LogEntryId   = e.LogEntryId
left join Property_2       as p2 on p2.LogEntryId   = e.LogEntryId
left join Property_3       as p3 on p3.LogEntryId   = e.LogEntryId
left join Property_4       as p4 on p4.LogEntryId   = e.LogEntryId
left join Property_5       as p5 on p5.LogEntryId   = e.LogEntryId
left join LogEntryCategory as x  on x.LogEntryId    = e.LogEntryId
left join LogCategory      as c  on c.LogCategoryID = x.LogCategoryID
```

This view (query) looks complicated and long; however, if you try a query like the one below and look at the execution plan, you may notice that property tables which are not mentioned in the select list are not included in the plan (not touched).

```
select
      LogCategoryName
    , LogTime
    , p1_Value
    , p2_Value
from dbo.vLogs
where LogCategoryName = 'some_category' 
  and LogTime between from_time and to_time
```

and if you need something simple like this

```
select max(p1_Value)
from dbo.vLogs
where LogTime between '2011-07-18' and '2011-07-19'
```

Here is the execution plan, as you can see only two tables are involved.

[image]

This is called table (join) elimination and you do need SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSql 9.x, ... for this to work --  will not work on MySql (yet).

Each time a property is added, you would have to add a new table and modify the view.

Comment: Thank you! If I had many properties, would this change your suggestion to normalize or is that regardless?

Comment: @JeffN825, it should be manageable number of properties. If it were 1000, there would be 1000+ rows in that query. I have some examples that are ~50, but use automated code generation. For large number, other solutions make more sense, including No-SQL, like Mongo, which are EAV under the hood.

Comment: But no matter what you wouldn't suggest stuffing it into a single field right?

Comment: @JeffN825 No, I would not suggest that.